# How to print json array using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, json

i am stuck at some json parsing, i am populating some fields using jquery's ajax function, i found the desired result, but dont know how to print it, here is my code

```
function logged_in_users() {
    $.ajax({
        url: site_url+'user/get_loggedin_users',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            $('#div_id').append(result.email_address)
        }
    }); 
}
```

while i have a result in my console response like,

```
[{"email_address":"abc@yahoo.com"},{"email_address":"abc@gmail.com"}]
```

while on the function side i am using,

```
echo json_encode($this->login_history_model->get_logged_in_users());
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an array of results, not just one result, so your success function won't work.

Change to:

```
success: function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, v) {
        // For each record in the returned array
        $('#div_id').append(v.email_address); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Haha, early bird catches the worm and all that.

Comment: @Chris Dixon, simply Superb!

Comment: @Barmer, Thank you for your attention, please contribute a little to show a gif image while ajax function is fetching records, Thanks in advance